# Makefile: rule that match multiple patterns

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching

I have this rule in my Makefile, that responds to flags I pass:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/disable_%:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    touch $(BUILD_DIR)/disable_$*
    rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/enable_$*
    cd $(BUILD_DIR) && rm -f Makefile   

$(BUILD_DIR)/enable_%:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    touch $(BUILD_DIR)/enable_$*
    rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/disable_$*
    cd $(BUILD_DIR) && rm -f Makefile
```

What this means is that when changing the flags by which I invoke the makefile, I can trigger some recompilations that could depend on these flags.
The code presented above is a bit redundant: you see that I remove a file, touch another and remove a Makefile in both cases. The only thing that changes is the name of the files that I touch/remove, and they are related.

For instance,

```
make clean
make enable_debug=yes enable_video=no # will compile from zero
make enable_debug=no enable_video=no  # flag change detected -> recompile some submodules that depend on this flag
```

Provided that the only thing that changes between the two rules ( `[en|dis]able` ), what I would like is to only have 1 generic rule, something like that:

```
# match 2 parts in the rule
$(BUILD_DIR)/%ble_%: 
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    touch $(BUILD_DIR)/(???)ble_$*  # should be $@
    rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/(???)able_$* # should be disable if $@ is enable and inverse
    cd $(BUILD_DIR) && rm -f Makefile
```

Is this possible ?

PS: Sorry if I didn't get the title correctly, I couldn't figure how to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/enable_% $(BUILD_DIR)/disable_%:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/*able_$*
    touch $@
    cd $(BUILD_DIR) && rm -f Makefile
```

Not literally what you wanted (multi-wildcards are forbidden in make), but does quite the same.

Comment: Are you sure that `make enable_toto=yes` will do `rm -f disable_toto` && `touch enable_toto` ?

Comment: I edited your code to make it work. Using rm, I can delete the previous file!

Comment: You could `rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/Makefile` when you remove other stuff; `rm` takes multiple file arguments and the `cd` is completely superfluous.

Comment: I don't believe the syntax you're using (`something=somevalue`) will result in any rules execution. Your rules have to be phony targets, which hardly could be wildcards, and using '=' sign will result in variable assignment, not request to build rule.